# how to add a button to maps info bubble

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add a button to my maps itemizedoverlay. Now i can draw an empty speech bubble using itemizedoverlay. But i want to add a button on it. I have tried to define that button as another overlay and add it to another geopoint and manage to make it seems like it is on the bubble. But when I zoom in or out, the location of the speech bubble and button change. I have tried to set them on the same geopoint. But after that the tap function of itemized overlay didn't run properly. I have checked a lot things such as https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons. I am not allowed to use external library. So i need you help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: mapviewbaloons, along with itemizedoverlay, have been depricated with the release of the Google Maps v2 API. You shouldn't be using this function. Anyway - are you trying to change the icon/marker? Or are you really trying to have 2 seperate "buttons," one for the speach bubble and one marking the location?

Comment: Exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: You mean 2 seperate buttons?